# cmake_current_source_dir used as avariable

Tags: cmake

Please check below scenerio :

cmakelists_1.txt

```
set( variable_name
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sub_folder1
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sub_folder2
    )
```

cmakelists_2.txt

```
include_directories(
    ${variable_name}
)
```

Now when cmakelists_2 executes it doesn't include the files present in sub_folders. But it works if I give absolute path for sub_folders in cmakelists_1.

Please point me if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` is always the current source directory where the CMakeLists.txt which mentions it lives.  So it expands to something different depending on which directory it is used from.  What is it expanding to for you, and how is that different from your hard-coded path that works?  Once you see the difference you'll know how to fix it, so in both files do this:

```
message(${variable_name})
```

Then re-run `cmake` and see what it prints.

Comment: Thanks John, ya its diffrent but can you please explain what is the standard/genralized way to solve this as I dont want hard-coded path.

Comment: Well you can use something based on PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR instead, which will never change.

Comment: Or, if you need to access a different project's directory, `ProjectName_SOURCE_DIR`.